# Ruby on rails: Store multiple row in different array

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm a beginner in Ruby on rails and i have some some problems with my request sql.

First I have this request:

```
Annonce.find_by_sql(
    "SELECT annonces.TitreAnnonce, annonces.Coins, categories.nom,
            regions.Nom as NomRegion  
     FROM annonces 
     INNER JOIN categories, regions 
     WHERE annonces.idCategories = categories.id and annonces.idRegions = regions.id 
     ORDER BY annonces.id DESC LIMIT 6")
```

I would like to store each row in a different array. I use `map{ |f| "#{f.nom} #{f.NomRegion} #{f.TitreAnnonce} #{f.Coins}"}`but the result is store in a only array.

My second problem is the following.   When I make my request in my html.erb file, the result is displayed on the bottom of my web page like this:

`[["Title1", 1500, "Car", "Quebec"], ["Title2", 50, "Car", "Title3"], ["Title4", 130, "Car", "Quebec"]]`

What can I do to NOT display this result.

Comment: You can see the arrays on the bottom of the page probably because you have `<%= @array.each do |element| %>` instead of `<% @array.each do |element| %>` (pay attention to the "equal" sign)

Comment: @Kkulikovskis is right: 
<% do some Ruby fun with no output %>
<%= "show the result of whatever happens here as output" %>

Comment: Thank you for your help. After searching during about 1 hour on the ruby documentation i found something talking about that.